# Jenkins failing to build docker image. script.sh docker not found

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr

I have a jenkins instance running on a EKS cluster and I'm trying to setup Jenkins to build my images and push to my ECR but it's not working because `docker` seems to be missing.

Here's my `Jenkinsfile`

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("build"){
            steps {
                sh('docker -v')
                sh('docker login --username AWS --password-stdin dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com')
                sh('docker build -t dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/test .')
                echo('building app')
            }
        }

        stage('test'){
            steps {
                sh('docker tag test dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/test')
                echo('testing app')
            }
        }

        stage('deploy'){
            steps {
                sh('docker push dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/test')
                echo('deploying app')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm running into an error of `script.sh: 1: docker: not found`.

What am I missing, do I need to install Docker on Jenkins, and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: What is agent any? What's happening?

Comment: `agent any` just means use any available agent for building

Comment: Do the agents have a docker daemon installed?

Comment: Yes, like Manuel pointed out, you need to install the docker daemon in the agent before running all of those steps

Comment: How do I install the docker daemon on this? Like I said, it's running in an EKS cluster if that makes any difference

Comment: Follow the links "Manage Jenkins" > Manage Nodes and Clouds. If you see just the master node, then probably the agents will be spawned on build request or the master is allowed to build as well. Otherwise you have to connect to your nodes and install a docker daemon. The agents needs the tools installed you use inside your build pipeline. You can also check, if you have a cloud setup configured in "Kubernetes Cloud Details"